# Proof for a rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I have this proof for Linear algebra, it is as follows:

> Let *A* be an $m × n$ matrix. Prove that $rank(A) = r$ if and only
>   if there is an invertible $m × m$ matrix $P$ and an invertible $n × n$ matrix $Q$ such
>   that 
>   $PAQ=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> I_r & 0{_r}{_,}{_n}{_-}{_r}\\
> 0{_m}{_-}{_r}{_,}{_r} & 0{_m}{_-}{_r}{_,}{_n}{_-}{_r}\\
> \end{pmatrix}$

Honestly, I have no idea what this question is really asking. I understand what rank is, but I have no idea how to figure it out given the matrix. I don't really understand what the subscripts under the $0$s in the matrix really mean either. Can anyone provide some guidance? I'm pretty new when it comes to proofs in linear algebra.

Comment: It's that (allegedly) long and tedious proof where you first do Gauss algorithm on the rows of the matrix, then you do it on the columns, then you permute rows and columns. Then you observe that every Gauss operation on the rows corresponds to multiplication on the left by an invertible matrix, and that every Gauss operation on the columns corresponds to multiplication on the right by an invertible matrix. A lot of chalk on the blackboard, a lot of handwaving from the lecturer. Very frustrating if you start from "I don't even know what's asking".

Comment: Geometrically, it's not so tedious.  rank $r$ means the image is an $r$ plane.  Rank-nullity theorem says you can find a basis of domain so that the first $r$ basis vectors map to that $r$ plane in the range, and the other $n-r$ basis vectors map to $0$.  Then just take the image of the first $r$ basis vectors as the the first $r$ vectors of a basis of the range.  In that basis, the linear transformation corresponding to $A$ is given by that matrix.  Changing basis is the same as applying invertible $P$ and $Q$

Comment: subscripts are probably the sizes of the objects, how many rows and columns of 0 et.c. so there's an $r \times r$ identity matrix  upper left and then padded right and down with zeros to get $m\times n$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Well, it’s certainly long and tedious if one goes about it that way, but quite short and straightforward with the approach sketched out by Callus.

Comment: Yes, those subscripts are just the dimensions of the blocks. What they’re describing is an $m\times n$ matrix with $r$ 1s along the main diagonal and zeros everywhere else.

Comment: @amd His is probably even the first proof I've seen in my life, but it got overwritten by some numerical analysis stuff a couple of years later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indices indicate the size of the submatrices, here $I_r$ is a $r\times r$ identity matrix and $0_{r,n-r}$ refers to a zero matrix of size $r\times n-r$.

What we have here is sometimes referred to as the normalform of the matrix determined by a linear map. As you know, a linear map $f:V\to W, x\to f(x)$ between finite dimensional linear spaces can always be rewritten in matrix form $A_f: V\to W, x \to A_f x$. Here the matrix $A_f$ depends on the choice of Bases for $V$ and $W$. Usually we choose the standard bases given by the unit vectors $e_1, e_2,\ldots,e_n$, but there are other choices. In particular for any matrix you can choose bases for $V$ and $W$ such that the matrix $A_f$ is in the normal form you are asked to prove.

Hint: Start out with a basis $(v_{n-r},\ldots,v_n)$ of $\ker f$ and extend it to a basis $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ of all of $V$. Then already you can say that $A_f$ looks like $\begin{pmatrix}*\cdots*&0\cdots0\\\vdots &\vdots\\
\underbrace{*\cdots*}_{r} &\underbrace{0\cdots0}_{n-r}\end{pmatrix}$

Now think about how to choose a basis of $W$ to make it look like the normal form. The matrices $P$ and $Q$ will then simply be the base change matrices from the standard base to the new bases.

Comment: +1 for figuring out what OP was actually having trouble with.

Comment: You rock dude! Definitely still took me a while to figure it out but I think that was a push in the right direction. Thanks so much!